# How to use a gateway for my SiganlR hubs?

Tags: c#, iis, signalr

I am using SiganlR to provide real time communication with an angular app, I have 9 hubs (this number will be incremented in the future) and each hub is created in a separated project, also each hub is broadcasting data each 1 second.

All hubs are authenticated using an Identity server.

The problem I am having is that when I want to host the hubs on IIS then I need to open 9 ports for each hub in order for the application to work, but when we tend to host the application on our clients servers he refused to let us open 9 ports for security reasons.

And because I am using Ocelot for the other services (normal api's) I thought to use it also for SignalR hubs but the problem is that Ocelot does not support authentication for websocket [Authentication with SignalR #1040](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/issues/1040)

I thought also about grouping all hubs into one project but this will cause some serious limitation for the message size and for the number of connected clients so I dumped the idea.

So I am looking for a solution to allow my clients to connect to hubs but with one opened port instead of 9 port.

Please let me know if I need to provide any further information.

Comment: When you deploy these applications on IIS, you can choose "Add application" in a site and with different [alias](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B87BK.png). Then you can access them through url http://hostname:port/alias. You just need to open one port for the site and all these applications can run in a site.